Apparent RA-Dec value with geocentric observer didnt match between Skyfield and Horizons
When I trying to match between Skyfield and Horizons JPL data (with observer in geocentric), I found that the both value have differences. Here's configurations I have:
MAKE_EPHEM=YES
COMMAND=10
EPHEM_TYPE=OBSERVER
CENTER='500@399'
START_TIME='2024-Nov-22'
STOP_TIME='2024-Nov-23'
STEP_SIZE='1 HOURS'
QUANTITIES='2,13,20,31'
REF_SYSTEM='ICRF'
CAL_FORMAT='CAL'
CAL_TYPE='M'
TIME_DIGITS='MINUTES'
ANG_FORMAT='HMS'
APPARENT='AIRLESS'
RANGE_UNITS='AU'
SUPPRESS_RANGE_RATE='NO'
SKIP_DAYLT='NO'
SOLAR_ELONG='0,180'
EXTRA_PREC='NO'
R_T_S_ONLY='NO'
CSV_FORMAT='YES'
OBJ_DATA='NO'

In 2024-Nov-22 00:00, for example, the Apparent RA is 15h 51m 59.22s and Apparent Declination of Sun is -20 11 08.4.
But in Skyfield, it show the apparent RA is 15h 50m 32.61s and apparent declination is -20deg 06' 35.6".
Here's skyfield code I use:
from skyfield.api import load

ts = load.timescale()
t = ts.utc(2024, 11, 22, 0)
planets = load('de440.bsp')
earth, sun = planets['earth'], planets['sun']

apparent = earth.at(t).observe(sun).apparent()
ra, dec, distance = apparent.radec()

print('RA:', ra)
print('Dec:', dec)


I get 2024-Nov-22 00:00     15 50 34.05 -20 06 40.1 from Horizons web, a few arc seconds from the Skyfield result. Are you sure you selected geocentric?

@amateurAstro The result you get is astrometric RA-Dec instead of apparent RA-Dec

Yes, it looks like Skyfield is giving you astrometric RA-Dec instead of apparent RA-Dec. Other differences are probably due to the EOP file. See High Precision Earth Orientation Parameter (EOP) Model under https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/manual.html#longterm

Here's a query with both astrometric & apparent data for the geocenter. https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&COMMAND=10&CENTER=500%40399&TLIST=%272024-Nov-22%27&QUANTITIES=%271%2C2%27&CSV_FORMAT=YES&OBJ_DATA=NO Also note that Horizons currently uses DE441

According to the skyfield docs, observe() gives astromentric coordinates, and observe().apparent() gives apparent coordinates.  So, if it really is displaying astrometric coordinates, that would be a major bug in Skyfield, and hard to believe no one had found it before. My bet is it's something else.

Take a look at the explanations that HORIZONS prints below the table of coordinates that it prints out. It explains the apparent coordinates this way:
 'R.A.__(a-app), DEC_(a-app),' =
  Airless apparent right ascension and declination of the target center
with respect to an instantaneous reference frame defined by the Earth equator
of-date (z-axis) and meridian containing the Earth equinox of-date (x-axis,
EOP-corrected IAU76/80). Compensated for down-leg light-time delay,
gravitational deflection of light, stellar aberration, precession & nutation.
Note: equinox (RA origin) is offset -53 mas from the of-date frame defined
by the IAU06/00a P & N system.

  Units: RA  in hours-minutes-seconds of time,   HH MM SS.ff{ffff}
         DEC in degrees-minutes-seconds of arc, sDD MN SC.f{ffff}

Thus, these are not permanent "J2000" coordinates (really, ICRS these days), but coordinates relative to the Earth's mean equator ­— coordinates, in other words, that are in a coordinate system that precesses with the Earth.
So give Skyfield an argument asking for a coordinate system that follows the Earth's precession, like this:
ra, dec, distance = apparent.radec(epoch='date')

The result will agree almost exactly with HORIZONS: an RA of 15h 51m 59.23s versus 15 51 59.22.
